# Блокировка строк в MySQL(PDO_MYSQL)

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Всем привет! Есть база **mfraffle** и таблица с именем **r_users**. Эта таблица содержит список зарегистрированных пользователей, а у каждого пользователя есть внутренний счёт, вот так выглядит таблица :

[image]

На сайте есть возможность переводить наличные со счёта на счёт и пополнять его из вне. Собственно вопрос : **как временно заблокировать только определённую строку в таблице на все операции, то есть запретить *читать* и *изменять* эту строку другим?**

Покажите пожалуйста пример на **PHP**.

Comment: определенную строку или определенного пользователя?

Comment: Определённую строку, просто я хочу чтобы больше никто не мог читать(пускай ждёт) и изменять(и тут пускай ждёт) определённую строку в таблице, пока кто-то 1 уже работает с этой строкою.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас проблема несколько шире, т.к. не понятно зачем вам блокировать только что созданную строку. Возможно решение вашей проблемы будет механизм транзакций краткая его суть такая: открывается транзакция, выполняется куча различных SQL запросов как записи так и чтения, при этом другие сессии с БД не видят изменений которые были сделаны во время транзакций, до тех пор, пока она не будет закоммичена.

А если нужно блокировать, то это нужно реализовывать руками. 
Вводить поле is_blocked, по-умолчанию 1 и где нужно проверять.

Comment: Строка создавалась не важно когда, о времени её создания я не говорил. Представьте, у пользователя есть 200 рублей, если со счёта пользователя я снимаю 200 рублей, а а другой сценарий почти одновременно(но позже) снимает 100, то на счёте останется 100 рублей, хотя денег у пользователя уже быть не должно, вот и начнётся неразбериха. Для этого мне и надо блокировать строку, покажите пример.

Comment: В вашем случае подойдет способ Mutex-блокировки. В MySQL реализуется с помощью 2-х функций GET_LOCK, RELEASE_LOCK
Суть проста: GET_LOCK принимает строковый параметр и возвращает 1 если никто другой не забирал блокировку с таким же именем, в противном случае он ожидает пока блокировка не будет снята функцией RELEASE_LOCK

Пример запроса:
GET_LOCK(user_id, 1); -- user_id -- id пользователя, 1 -- таймаут в секундах ( насколько я помню )
UPDATE r_users SET cash = cash - transfer_value WHERE user_id = id;
RELEASE_LOCK( user_id );

А вообще InnoDB использует строковую-блокировку, MyISAM -- табличну

Comment: А вообще InnoDB использует строковую-блокировку, MyISAM -- табличную
Это значит, если написать такой код:
UPDATE r_users SET cash = cash - transfer_value WHERE user_id = id AND cash >= transfer_value;

То он гарантировано будет отрабатывать.